# how can i grep the interface names given in following output of netstat -i

Tags: bash, grep

Hi i want grep the interfaces names as a list , am getting the table of interfaces with netstat -i and it looks like this :
[image]

thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use also `awk` to simplify expressions:

```
netstat -i | awk '{print $1}' | grep -vE '(Kernel|Iface)'
```

In this case we are using `awk` to print only first column and after that we filter out words from first two lines of `netstat` output.

P.S. Or even shorter (thanks to @etan-reisner)

```
netstat -i | awk '! /(Kernel|Iface)/ {print $1}'
```

Comment: There is virtually *never* a need to pipe `grep` to `awk` or `awk` to `grep`. `awk '! /(Kernel|Iface)/ {print $1}'` or `awk 'NR>2{print $1}' for example

Comment: Yes, thank you for this tip. Probably author will use it.

Comment: Better like `netstat -i | awk '! /(Kernel|Iface|Table)/ {print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

i got the preferred output with `ifconfig -a | sed 's/[ \t].*//;/^$/d'` 
though `netstat -i | awk '{print $1}' | grep -vE '(Kernel|Iface)'` is also working , but i will prefer my solution since am writing a Qt QProcess and more arguments and programs will be not a solution . thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell itself to test/parse the interface names as well without calling either `awk` or `sed`:

```
netstat -i | while read iface data; do 
  [ $(expr "$iface" : "Kernel\|Iface") -eq 0 ] && 
  printf "%s\n" "$iface"
done
```

Or as a one-liner (not too long):

```
netstat -i | while read iface data; do [ $(expr "$iface" : "Kernel\|Iface") -eq 0 ] && printf "%s\n" "$iface"; done
```